# Null Error on WinForm Combobox

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, combobox

I am using WinForms and MySQL in my project.

My table structure is...

[image]

In my project I have three combo boxes and one TextBox. The "option" ComboBox contains three values:

1. City
2. State
3. Country

When I select the City, State and Country ComboBoxes must be selected.

[image]

When I select the State, the Country ComboBoxes must be selected.

[image]

When I select the Country, there's no need to select the State and Country ComboBoxes.

[image]

I tried to insert this data with this code:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.1.100;User Id=mcubic;password=mcs@2011$;database=mcs;Persist Security Info=True");
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into test (name1,option1,state,country) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + cmbo_Options.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','" + cmbo_state.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','" + cmbo_country.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')", connection);
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

When all ComboBoxes are selected, this code worked correctly. But when the State ComboBox is not selected, then it throws a NullReferenceException.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Null Error.

So I updated my code:

```
string country = cmbo_country.SelectedItem.ToString();
string state = cmbo_state.SelectedItem.ToString();
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.1.100;User Id=mcubic;password=mcs@2011$;database=mcs;Persist Security Info=True");
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into test (name1,option1,state,country) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + cmbo_Options.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','" + state + "','" + country + "')", connection);
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

I can't escape this error. How should my code be for this project?

Comment: Debug your code, find exact line that throws the exception. ...SelectedItem can be null.

Comment: cmbo_country.SelectedItem.ToString(); gives error.How to solve this?.

Comment: So, then ToString() throw the error because combobox is empty or there is no selected item. You should handle this situation, for example - write 'if' condition.

Comment: can i go for cmbobox.Text Propriety?

Comment: You can find this information in MSDN or just try to test it. But I'd suggest you to initialize your combobox - fill values and select default item (for example - SelectedIndex = 0). It will help you to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have a easy way,

```
 string country ="";
if(cmbo_country.SelectedItem != null)
country = cmbo_country.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string state = "";
if(cmbo_state.SelectedItem !=null)
state = cmbo_state.SelectedItem.ToString();
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=192.168.1.100;User Id=mcubic;password=mcs@2011$;database=mcs;Persist Security Info=True");
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into test (name1,option1,state,country) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + cmbo_Options.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','" + state + "','" + country + "')", connection);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
```

In this you don't want any try and Catch,..

Answer (score 0):

Try `cmbo_country.Text`

The easiest solution would be by using `SWITCH` in your code.

Here's a simple `Psuedocode` for your application.

```
MySqlCommand command;
switch (cmbo_country.Text)
{
    case "City":
    {
       command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into test (name1,option1,state,country) VALUES ('','','','')");
       break;
    }
    case "State":
    {
       command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into test (name1,option1,country) VALUES ('','','')");
       break;
    }
    case "Country":
    {
       command = new MySqlCommand("Insert into test (name1,option1) VALUES ('','')");
       break;
    }
    default:
       // prompt the user to select an option.
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the 'break's between cases! ;)

Comment: Is three Query is needed for one operation?.

Comment: only one query will be executed and it will be base on the condition

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the insert statement so that you are not inserting into the `state` column if empty:

One simple way of doing it is to just add an if statement:

```
string sql;
if (cmbo_State.SelectedItem == null)
{
    sql = string.Format("Insert into test (name1,option1,country) 
        Values ('{0}','{1}','{2}')", textBox1.Text, 
        cmbo_Options.SelectedItem.ToString(), cmbo_country.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
else
{
    sql = string.Format("Insert into test (name1,option1,state,country) 
        Values ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')", textBox1.Text, 
        cmbo_Options.SelectedItem.ToString(), cmbo_state.SelectedItem.ToString()
        cmbo_country.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to put a try in combobox selected item code,..

```
 try
    {
        string country = cmbo_country.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string state = cmbo_state.SelectedItem.ToString();

    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Sorry For that,

You can Try this

```
try
{
    string country = cmbo_country.SelectedItem.ToString();           
}
catch{}

try
{       
    string state = cmbo_state.SelectedItem.ToString();

}
catch{}
```

Now the this code fulfill your requirement. ok?

Comment: -1 Like 'try to put a try' wording, but this is just hiding the problem. Use the debugger to find out where the problem is.

Comment: but it solve the error he will get the solution too quick. Is it Correct?

Comment: no if country is not selected the first line itself it returns, exception